# Java programming

Tags: java, interview

Can anyone help me to suggest some links to learn practical Java programming. I want to move to Selenium testing and the interview I faced they are asking about Java programming but I'm not able to give answer please help me in this case

Comment: This website is not for such generalized question. You should ask very specific query related to testing. simple google search would have done the job.

Answer (score 3):

**Below are the top 3 search results from google search for "top java related interview questions":**

http://www.javatpoint.com/corejava-interview-questions

http://career.guru99.com/top-100-core-java-interview-questions/

http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2013/06/top-25-most-frequently-asked-core-java.html

**Below are the top 3 search results from google search for "top Selenium related interview questions"**

http://www.guru99.com/top-100-selenium-interview-questions-answers.html

http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/selenium-interview-questions-part-1/

http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/selenium-interview-questions-answers/

This could be a good starting to prepare for Interview Questions.

**For some Java programs below urls could be a good starting point.**

http://www.javatpoint.com/java-tutorial

http://www.guru99.com/java-tutorial.html